I am repurposing a Logitech M815 and need help figuring out how to pass signals through it
Good Evening, like the title states I am repurposing an M815 which is a cheap logitech mouse. for a project and need to pass a signal through its circuit board with a micro controller (probably ESP 32) to simulate a mouse click (this is just a proof of concept I understand there are way easier software solutions to solve that problem). My problem is I can't seem to figure out how the buttons work, I've tried closing the circuit and looking at the pinouts for common mice switches (with there being 3 pins a Common Pin, a NO pin and a "dummy" pin. Does anyone know any resources where I can learn what kind of button it is and how to replicate its functionality? 

what's an M815?

it is a relatively cheap mouse from logitech, I will edit my post so I don't confuse anyone else. The model of the mouse doesn't really matter I just want to find out where I can go to understand what kind of circuit its using and how it works.

I don't think we can really know the exact features of this device since it's proprietary but generally speaking, you'll have a microcontroller that can keep track of movement and click events and "translates" that to a recognizable USB waveform for the computer to understand. When it comes to reverse engineering, it's probably better to think of the system conceptually first, understanding a general architecture.

Also how do you know it's specifically an ESP32? I know plenty of wireless mouses (mice?) that use a Nordic Semiconductor or Texas Instruments Bluetooth MCU as their choice of this type of device.

Please can you take a photo in focus; and a photo of the top side too.

to answer to concerns at once, im trying to add an external ESP32 wired into the two terminals on the mouse button to mimic a button press. So far I have figured out that optical mice have some sort of polling or clock signal and its not as simple as a circuit being open or closed

use a relay ...

"some sort of polling or clock signal" ... this would be very surprising across the switch.  Why do you think it's like this, and not something simple?

The reason i said there was a polling or clock signal is that when I checked the voltages with a multimeter across the two pins of the button there was a rising and falling voltage at a steady pattern. I could be wrong but it was just my observation.

I'm guessing you mean Logitech M185, there's doesn't seem to be an M815
The switches are ordinary switches, and so you should be able to make your mouse clicks by shorting the pads in the obvious way.
I suggest you unsolder one and check its pins with a continuity tester.
Here's a video where Logitech mouse switches are replaced by an Omron D2FC-F-7N: these are simple single normally-open contacts with a dummy pin (it's a different model mouse, but the switches look similar).

From Omron datasheet

Sorry for the mistake on the mouse name I completely missed it, but yes despite there being current running through i found a way to short the pins to have it send a click signal. Thank you for your help

@WumboTheSecond the changing voltage you see with a voltmeter sounds like erroneous readings you get when there's a fast-changing signal that would make sense on an oscilloscope.  (Specifically: you might have a high-rate, 1kHz say, scanning the switches, and the sampling frequency of the meter makes interference beats which looks like a slowly-changing voltage.)
